# JavaScript on iOS: preventDefault on touchstart without disabling scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, events, scroll

I am working with JavaScript and jQuery in an UIWevView on iOS.

I'v added some javascript event handler that allow me to capture a touch-and-hold event to show a message when someone taps an img for some time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timeoutId = 0;
    var messageAppeared = false;

    $('img').on('touchstart', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {           

            /* Show message ... */
            messageAppeared = true;

        }, 1000);

    }).on('touchend touchcancel', function(event) {                                

        if (messageAppeared) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        messageAppeared = false;        
    });
});
```

This works well to show the message. I added the two "event.preventDefault();" lines to stop imgs inside links to trigger the link.

The problem is: This also seems to prevent drag events to scroll the page from happen normally, so that the user wouldn't be able to scroll when his swipe happens to begin on an img.

How could I disable the default link action without interfering with scrolling?

Comment: I pulled my hair our for this issue..... shitttt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you have to ask a question on stack overflow to find the answer yourself. There is indeed a solution to my problem, and it's as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timeoutId = 0;

    $('img').on('touchstart', function(event) {

        var imgElement = this;

        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {           

            $(imgElement).one('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            /* Show message ... */

        }, 1000);

    }).on('touchend touchcancel', function(event) {                                
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });
});
```

### Explanation

- No preventDefault() in the touch event handlers. This brings back scrolling behavior (of course).
- Handle a normal click event once if the message appeared, and prevent *it's* default action.

Answer (score 10):

You put me on the right track Stefan, having me think the other way around. For anyone still scratching their head over this, here's my solution.

I was trying to allow visitors to scroll through images horizontally, without breaking vertical scrolling. But I was executing custom functionality and waiting for a vertical scroll to happen. Instead, we should allow regular behavior first and wait for a specific gesture to happen like Stefan did.

For example:

```
$("img").on("touchstart", function(e) {
    var touchStart = touchEnd = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    var touchExceeded = false;

    $(this).on("touchmove", function(e) {
        touchEnd = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

        if(touchExceeded || touchStart - touchEnd > 50 || touchEnd - touchStart > 50) {
            e.preventDefault();

            touchExceeded = true;

            // Execute your custom function.
        }
    });

    $(this).on("touchend", function(e) {
        $(this).off("touchmove touchend");
    });
});
```

So basically we allow default behavior until the horizontal movement exceeds 50 pixels.

The `touchExceeded` variable makes sure our function still runs if we re-enter the initial < 50 pixel area.

(Note this is example code, `e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX` is NOT cross browser compatible.)

Comment: Just curious, but shouldn't that be `one` instead of `on` for `touchend`?  Haven't tried the code, but it seems like it might bind too many times to touchend, while there should be a 1-to-1 touchstart to touchend ratio.

Comment: Good question. It should unbind itself (and the `touchmove` binding) instantly, but still, `one` might indeed work more efficiently. Feel free to mess around with it and see what works best.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at a gesture library like [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) which covers all of the main gesture events across devices.